# How to get the path to the current workspace/screen's wallpaper on OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa, nsworkspace

Since AppKit version 10.7, [NSWorkspace.desktopImageForScreen](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/desktopImageURLForScreen:) may return a path to a folder instead of a file's URL which is currently the wallpaper. This folder is the the place from where the wallpapers will be sequentially picked up for display. (Search for `setDesktopImageURL` in the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/)).

In case the user has set the desktop image to change randomly every thirty minutes or so, is there any way of determining what are the currently active wallpapers per screen in OSX?

---

**Update**: Based no the answer by @l'L'l, I created a small Mac OSX app to conveniently find the currently active Wallpapers: https://github.com/musically-ut/whichbg

Comment: I know there are a few ways to acquire the current desktop image name (random or static). I don't have multiple displays so I can't tell you if the methods I know of return the info for each screen; I can post a solution provided you are still interested.

Comment: @l'L'l That would be a start and might give me a hint as to where to look. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On `OS X 10.10` there is a `SQLite` 3.x database named `desktoppicture.db`. This db file stores info such as the current desktop picture, directory, space, interval, etc. when a timed random desktop picture transition happens or when there's any change to System Preferences > Desktop:

### Objective-C

```
// Get Current Desktop Picture

- (IBAction)getDesktopPicture:(id)sender {

    [self getCurrentDesktop];
}

-(void)getCurrentDesktop {

    NSMutableArray *sqliteData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *appSup = [paths firstObject];
    NSString *dbPath = [appSup stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Dock/desktoppicture.db"];

    sqlite3 *database;
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
        sqlite3_stmt *sel;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &sel, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(sel) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *data = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(sel, 0)];
                [sqliteData addObject:data];
            }
        }
    }
    NSUInteger cnt = [sqliteData count] - 1;
    NSLog(@"Desktop Picture: %@", sqliteData[cnt]);
    NSLog(@"%@",sqliteData);

    sqlite3_close(database); 
}
```

Result:

> 2015-06-23 14:36:04.470 CurrentDesktop[72591:87862519] Desktop
>   Picture: Poppies.jpg 2015-06-23 14:36:04.470
>   CurrentDesktop[72591:87862519] (
>       "60.0",
>       1,
>       "Poppies.jpg" )

There are quite a few different other ways you can get the data from this file (eg. `NSTask`, `Bash`, `AppleScript`, etc. This is my preferred solution since it's native mac code; it's simple enough to make portable for something else though.

Comment: Neat! Is this an undocumented feature? If so, is there a short summary somewhere of what the solutions were like for older versions?

Comment: * I'm not sure if this would be classified as an undocumented feature, but rather what seems to be the only way I presume currently works with timed random images. I'm not aware of other solutions that might have existed previously, although [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/301573/499581) perhaps takes a similar approach, but in a more generic manner.