# Seamlessly change all desktop spaces' wallpaper on Mac without killall Dock

Tags: macos, applescript

I would like to change the wallpaper on ALL desktops including spaces on Mac but without needing to call `killall Dock` each minute. (Dock restarting forces wallpaper refresh).

I have an AppleScript that changes the desktop wallpaper instantly:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell every desktop to set picture to wallpaperPath
```

but that only changes the wallpaper on the active space (meaning that if the main desktop is not active, its background will not change).

I found this question [How to loop through all Mac desktop spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185506/how-to-loop-through-all-mac-desktop-spaces) which suggests updating wallpaper path values in the SQLite database located at `~/Library/Application Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db`. This changes the wallpaper at every space which is great but it requires restart of the dock using `killall Dock` which is undesirable as it disrupts the workflow.

My question is - is there some way to combine these two approaches? Seamlessly change wallpapers on every desktop space?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I have no preferred language, it can be in C, Swift, Python, Bash, AppleScript etc.

Comment: Actually - changing it on all spaces is not needed. I just need the wallpaper to refresh on all the main desktops (on each monitor) no matter which space is active (I use fullscreen apps - therefore each fullscreen app gets its own space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

I am looping through all available screens and setting the wallpaper using [setDesktopImageURL:forScreen:options:error:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1527228-setdesktopimageurl?language=objc):

```
for screen in NSScreen.screens {
    try! NSWorkspace.shared.setDesktopImageURL(url, for: screen, options: [:])
}
```

This changes the wallpapers seamlessly, without the need for `killall Dock` on all the screens but only if the desktop is the active space.

To make sure the wallpaper is changed when I am on another space (usually a fullscreen app), I added an observer for `NSWorkspace.activeSpaceDidChangeNotification` on the `NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter` which sets the desktop images again (using the code above). So whenever I go back to the desktop, this notification is invoked and the wallpaper is seamlessly updated.

I even went one step further and added the same observer also for the `NSWorkspace.didWakeNotification` which updates the wallpaper as soon as the device wakes up which is cool!

Answer (score 0):

macOS Sonoma seems to use a new `.plist` file for wallpaper/screensaver related things, located at `~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.wallpaper/Store/Index.plist`.

You can edit this `.plist` to achieve what you're looking for.

1. Go to `System Settings` > `Wallpaper` and make sure to set a wallpaper from a folder you added yourself and that "Show on all Spaces" is on.
2. Enter the following in a terminal:

```bash
new_wallpaper_path="/path/to/wallpaper.jpg"; \
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set AllSpacesAndDisplays:Desktop:Content:Choices:0:Files:0:relative file:///$new_wallpaper_path" ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.wallpaper/Store/Index.plist && \
killall WallpaperAgent
```

GitHub issue that helped me figure this out: https://github.com/JohnCoates/Aerial/issues/1332