# How to change OS X wallpaper programmatically?

Tags: swift

First : I'm new with Swift developpement.
I'm trying to make a Swift app that will be able to change the user desktop wallpaper every X minutes.
Imagine the wallpapers are in the "Pictures" folder, named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg etc ...
So I have the path.
 
But I don't find how to make it !

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954492/how-to-get-the-path-to-the-current-workspace-screens-wallpaper-on-osx) url looks to be a good direction to search, but I don't find anybody who ask the question on the net (It can't be ...)

Comment: Yap, I'll have a look, thanks :)